# How to auto resize cocoa xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, autoresize

Is there any way to trigger the auto resize for different devices without using auto layout and size classes? 
I use predefine objects (UIButtons, textfield... etc) but mostly I use dynamic custom objects and I have issues with the resizing on different devices. 
I'm looking for the old way when we didn't needed to use constrains and auto layout + size classes.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform the resize logic in your `UIViewController`, add an ivar to store a `CGSize` and initialise it to `CGSizeZero`, then override `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and compare the size of the view to your stored variable. If they are different, store the new size and update the frames of your views, if they are the same, `return`.

If you want to have your resize logic in a `UIView`, do the same but override `layoutSubviews` instead. Don't forget to call `super`.

Comment: I have some system on lvl view in view in view ... but I was call it in viewDidLoad... I will try your idea and the above one and I will inform you who works best...

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoresize masks which are the old school version of autolayout and size classes

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100.0f)];
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

There's a few of them to help you get the desired results

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIViewAutoresizing) {
    UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
```

Personally once you're feeling confident I'd look at getting your head around programmatically creating some autolayout but this is a start.